# Custom store view per customer group

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, store-view, customer-group

I need a solution for showing a **different store view** to **different customer group**.

For example:

> Store view 1 must be displayed to the Customer Group 1 and  Store view
>   2 must be displayed to the Customer Group 2

Is there any way to do that? I've looked for any kind of solution or plugin but I cannot find anything useful.
Hope somebody can help me. Cheers!

**Magento 2.3**

Comment: where you want to  show at frontend or  backend?